# Get name of AirPlay device using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avplayer

When AirPlay is enabled in a MPMoviePlayerController, it displays a text "This video is playing on *device name* ". When using AirPlay with an AVPlayer, is there any way to programatically get the device name?

Comment: It appears, from the resounding silence, there is no way to programatically get the device name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After searching in other frameworks to get the name of the Apple TV you're connected to, I finally found this information in the AudioToolbox framework. There may be other ways to get this, but so far I have not found another way. Hope this helps.

You'll need to import the AudioToolbox framework:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

and then a method to call when you want to detect if airplay is available

```
- (BOOL)isAirplayActive {
  CFDictionaryRef currentRouteDescriptionDictionary = nil;
  UInt32 dataSize = sizeof(currentRouteDescriptionDictionary);
  AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteDescription, &dataSize, &currentRouteDescriptionDictionary);

  self.deviceOutputType = nil;
  self.airplayDeviceName = nil;

  if (currentRouteDescriptionDictionary) {
    CFArrayRef outputs = CFDictionaryGetValue(currentRouteDescriptionDictionary, kAudioSession_AudioRouteKey_Outputs);
    if(CFArrayGetCount(outputs) > 0) {
      CFDictionaryRef currentOutput = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(outputs, 0);

      //Get the output type (will show airplay / hdmi etc
      CFStringRef outputType = CFDictionaryGetValue(currentOutput, kAudioSession_AudioRouteKey_Type);

      //If you're using Apple TV as your ouput - this will get the name of it (Apple TV Kitchen) etc
      CFStringRef outputName = CFDictionaryGetValue(currentOutput, @"RouteDetailedDescription_Name");

      self.deviceOutputType = (NSString *)outputType;
      self.airplayDeviceName = (NSString *)outputName;

      return (CFStringCompare(outputType, kAudioSessionOutputRoute_AirPlay, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo);
    }
  }
  return NO;
}
```

Comment: Sounds promising! I will try this and get back.

Comment: in iOS 8 you need to change: if(CFArrayGetCount(outputs) > 0) to: if(outputs && CFArrayGetCount(outputs) > 0)

Comment: Can some help with a swift version for the same?

Answer (score 10):

Starting from iOS7 AudioToolbox API for currentRoute becomes deprecated:

Apple instead made currentRoute API available to you in AudioSession, which allows retrieving it's port information as well as listening to audioRouteChangeNotification in a nice way:

```
NSString* airplayName = [self activeAirplayOutputRouteName];
if (airplayName) {
    //airplay is active

}

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(audioRouteHasChangedNotification:) name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification object:[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]];
```

(what you want to get is the `portType` of `portDescription` of `audioSession.currentRoute`):

```
- (NSString*)activeAirplayOutputRouteName
{
    AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    AVAudioSessionRouteDescription* currentRoute = audioSession.currentRoute;
    for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription* outputPort in currentRoute.outputs){
        if ([outputPort.portType isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortAirPlay])
            return outputPort.portName;
    }

    return nil;
}

- (void)audioRouteHasChangedNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I'll post a similar answer than [ambientlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2380455/ambientlight) for swift. Maybe it is helpful for someone in the future.

```
private func addAirplayNotifier() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("airplayChanged:"), name: AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification, object: AVAudioSession.sharedInstance())
}

func airplayChanged(sender:NSNotification) -> Bool {
    var airplayConnected = false
    let currentRoute = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute
    for output in currentRoute.outputs {
        if output.portType == AVAudioSessionPortAirPlay {
            print("Airplay Device connected with name: \(output.portName)")
            airplayConnected = true
        }
    }
    print("Disconnect Airplay")
    return airplayConnected
}
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
private func addAirplayNotifier() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector("airplayChanged:"), name:NSNotification.Name.AVAudioSessionRouteChange, object: AVAudioSession.sharedInstance())
}
```

Comment: This one worked great and is simple, I'm going to the top with you

Comment: You helped me in the future!! I googled for an hour to try to find out when an airplay destination was chosen!

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4**

```
private func addAirplayNotifier() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(airplayChanged),
        name: AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification,
        object: AVAudioSession.sharedInstance())
}

@objc func airplayChanged() {
    isAirPlaying = false
    let currentRoute = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute
    for output in currentRoute.outputs where output.portType == AVAudioSession.Port.airPlay {
        print("Airplay Device connected with name: \(output.portName)")
        isAirPlaying = true
    }
}
```