# How to get the AirPlay device name without using iOS7 deprecated methods

Tags: ios, ios7, airplay

I'm using the method described here [Get name of AirPlay device using AVPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044894/get-name-of-airplay-device-using-avplayer/14388326#14388326) to retrieve the name of the AirPlay device connected.

But  `AudioSessionGetProperty` and `kAudioSession_AudioRouteKey_Outputs` are deprecated in iOS7. I'm looking for an alternative method to do this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from iOS6 AudioSession exposes currentRoute to you, which allows retrieving it's port information as well as listening to audioRouteChangeNotification.
(so you no longer need to use C-based API from AudioToolbox framework):

```
NSString* airplayName = [self activeAirplayOutputRouteName];
if (airplayName) {
    //airplay is active

}
```

(what you want to get is the portDescription of currentAudioRoute):

```
- (NSString*)activeAirplayOutputRouteName
{
    AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    AVAudioSessionRouteDescription* currentRoute = audioSession.currentRoute;
    for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription* outputPort in currentRoute.outputs){
        if ([outputPort.portType isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortAirPlay])
            return outputPort.portName;
    }

    return nil;
}
```