# AirPlay - programatically disconnect before switching the other device

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, chromecast, airplay

I have an application for video streaming. It has ability to make mirroring AirPlay (Apple Tv). Now I'm trying to add Google Chromecast connection. I added button and everything working just I expected. Here is my case: I want user only be able to connect 1 device at the moment. For example if user already conneceted to AirPlay when user tap on Chromecast, I want to disable AirPlay programmatically.

Here's how I checked external playback status:

```
self.videoPlayer.isExternalPlaybackActive
```

Here's how I checked is AirPlay connected:

```
- (BOOL)isAirPlayConnected {
    return self.airPlayButton.isWirelessRouteActive;
}
```

I know this is how I disabled all external display:

```
self.videoPlayer.allowsExternalPlayback = NO;
self.videoPlayer.usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive = NO;
```

I already listening: 
`MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification` and `MPVolumeViewWirelessRouteActiveDidChangeNotification` notifications.

Bu couldn't find solution for **programatically disconnect before switching the other**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to add an observer to get the airplay event changes something similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35479281/2000162 and manage the logic to connect-disconnect the chromecast

Comment: Thank you, @TomCobo I already manage logic but din't find any solution for programatically disconnect before switching other.

Comment: From the top of my head I think you can't disconnect AirPlay programatically. Not sure about it. You can allow the allowExternalPlayback in AVplayer. Look at this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayer/usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive   This way you could change allowsExternalPlayback var

Comment: I'm already using "allowsExternalPlayback" like I said. But It's for all external playback I think. Also I'm thinking same with you about disconnecting AirPlay programmatically not possible probably. Event if I could make it, Apple will reject it. But I didn't find any "forbidden" about it yet :)

Comment: Any update for this question? I need this feature in my app.

Comment: No, unfortunately.