# Get Connected AirPlay Device Name

Tags: swift, avaudiosession, airplay

I want to get the name of the AirPlay or Bluetooth device my iPhone is connected to. I have somewhat achieved this with the following code...

```
let currentRoute = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute
for output in currentRoute.outputs {
    print("Connected port name: \(output.portName)")
}
```

But, whenever my iPhone is connected to an AirPlay device such as a HomePod or Apple TV, the `portName` returned is just `"Speaker"`. I would like to get the name of the HomePod or Apple TV. Whenever my device is connected to Bluetooth, though, this works. For example, whenever I am connected to my AirPods, the name `"Jacob's AirPods"` is returned. Whenever I am connected to another Bluetooth device, the correct name is returned.

I believe that getting the name of the AirPlay device should be possible because Apple does it in their Apple Music app and system-wide. Like bellow...

[image: Sceenshot of AirPlay 2 window on iOS 12]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Only Apple is able to always retrieve the name of a wireless audio device, and the external API currently does not always return the personalized name of an audio device. If this is a feature you would like to see feel free to file a bug with [Feedback Assistant](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/welcome).

Comment: @DaveAMoore Well it’s strange because every once in a while, I will receive the name of the AirPlay device

Comment: @JacobCavin have you had a look at this [Get name of AirPlay device using AVPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13044894/4056108) it has some promising answers