# identify the name of the AirPlay device for accessibility

Tags: ios, swift, airplay

I'm trying to identify the name of the device when AirPlay is active. I would like to use the name for VoiceOver.

[Test Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2Cmg.jpg)

With the snippet below, all I'm getting is "AirPlay".

Here is a snippet:

```
var externalDeviceName: String {
    let currentRoute = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute
    var port: String?

    for output in currentRoute.outputs where output.portType == AVAudioSession.Port.airPlay {
        port = output.portName
    }
    return port ?? "unknown"
}
```

I referenced a couple of posts so far, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044894/get-name-of-airplay-device-using-avplayer).

Is getting the device name not possible?